# Cannot find Dash in Lubuntu... first time user

Tags: unity-dash

I have not used any type of linux distro for years, so I may as well be a first time user here.
I installed Lubuntu on an old laptop (Toshiba Satellite Pro) just to check it and see how i go with it.
I am using transmission as my torrent client, and wanted it to start when I login....  I did a search and apparently I need to open Dash,and from there add it to the startup applications, but for the life of me I cannot find "dash" or "Startup Applications". There was also mention of a sidebar.. but I don't have one of these, and there was also reference to clicking the ubuntu icon in the top right hand corner, but again.. I don't have this.
SO I am rather confused at this point in time.

I managed to install sysinfo and it tells me I am running 
release: Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial)
GNOME: unknown
Kernel: 4.4.0-28-generic
GCC version: no gcc detected
Xorg version: 1.18.3 (18th May 2016)

Just on that, it says Ubuntu there as you can see... I know Lubuntu us based Ubuntu, so I am confused if I have downloaded and installed Ubuntu or Lubuntu..Oh the joys of new toys!

thanks to anybody that can help me out here.

Answer (score 1):

According to [a web page](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/lubuntu), you can autostart programs in Lubuntu 16.04 this way:

1. Go to the menu button → `Preferences` → `Default applications for LXSession`
2. Click `Autostart`
3. Click `Add`
4. Type in the command to run
5. Click `Add` again

Answer (score 1):

Dash is a feature of the Unity desktop, which is used by standard Ubuntu. Lubuntu, while an Ubuntu "flavor," uses a different, lightweight desktop called LXDE instead. It doesn't have Dash.